# Hash/achor url needs to display hidden jquery/css div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, tabs

this problem has been driving me nuts, although I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face because I'm often an idiot.

I made a tabbed page based off this code which uses both CSS and jQuery.
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-use-css-and-jquery-to-hide-and-show-tab-content/

The tabbed content also needs to be accessible via a drop down CSS menu. You can see it here.
http://jsfiddle.net/4N63A/

This is the code I'm using.

```
$('.subSection-tabs > li > a').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();//stop browser to take action for clicked anchor

//get displaying tab content jQuery selector
var active_tab_selector = $('.subSection-tabs > li.selected > a').attr('href');                 
//find actived navigation and remove 'selected' css
var actived_nav = $('.subSection-tabs > li.selected');
actived_nav.removeClass('selected');

//add 'selected' css into clicked navigation
$(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');

//hide displaying tab content
$(active_tab_selector).removeClass('selected');
$(active_tab_selector).addClass('hide');

//show target tab content
var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');
$(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
$(target_tab_selector).addClass('selected');
 });

//checks for hash tag in URL to display correct div 
var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );
if (hash) $('.subSection-tabs > li > a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');

//force browser URL to update with the selected hash tag
$("a[href^=#]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState({}, "", this.href);
    //show/hide div from drop down
    var active_nav_selector = $('ul > li.navHash > a').attr('href');
    $(active_nav_selector).removeClass('selected');
    $(active_nav_selector).addClass('hide');
    var target_nav_selector = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target_nav_selector).removeClass('hide');
    $(target_nav_selector).addClass('selected');
});
```

So when a user click on the Dropdown link and then "Tab 2", the url in the browser changes to #tab2, but the tab 2 div and content doesn't display. Changing it from the "Show Tab 2" tab works as expected and puts the appropriate hash (#tab2) in the browser window. I need the drop down navigation's links to work correctly so users can use the back button. You can click on the Google link to see what I mean.

Oh goodness, I hope I am explaining this correctly. Basically, the drop down menu needs to also show and hide the correct divs. My script can be viewed at /script.js

Thanks so much in advance. I really appreciate any help because I am going nuts. If I could bake you cupcakes I would. I make awesome mojito ones. You can pretend to eat them.

**UPDATE:** I added the show/hide class function to my Jsfiddle's function(e), and now the drop down shows the correct div but doesn't hide the previous. I'm so close, yet so far!

Comment: post your code !!!!! create [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) demo !!!!

Comment: Okay, rynhe. http://jsfiddle.net/4N63A/

Answer (score 0):

You're using the history.pushState which gives you the #tab2
but looking at the js provided, there isn't any logic to show the div content
like

```
$("a[href^=#]").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
history.pushState({}, "", this.href);
    // show the tab content with the same name (use id since they're the same) as href~    
});
```

Also as a good practice - put your jquery and scripts below of the body 
(this serves two purposes,
 1. the styles load first which presents the page to the user quicker
 2. your jquery scripts can check whether the "document" is indeed ready and show

(seems your dropbox doesn't like running the jquery library) - so I recommend that in future, you use github pages, codepen, or a jsfiddle to demo something with js

Added JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/denistsoi/UD4Hx/

Seems to be working fine, but even then, this doesn't show the history.pushstate working~

Comment: Thanks, Denis. I added the show/hide class function to my Jsfiddle, and now the drop down shows the correct div but doesn't hide the previous. I'm so close, yet so far! I appreciate your help as to calling out the pushState function and advising to put scripts after the closing body tag. I always wonder why some people did that. Anyway, here's my updated Jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/boobunny/4N63A/2/